# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence coming in my CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition

I am building a CNN architecture for face recognition on own dataset.
First here's my code:

```
classifier = keras.Sequential()
classifier.add(keras.layers.Convolution2D(16,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape = (256,256,3),activation = swish,padding='same',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Convolution2D(16,kernel_size=(3, 3),activation = swish,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2))
classifier.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2),strides=2))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Convolution2D(32,kernel_size=(3, 3),activation = swish,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Convolution2D(32,kernel_size=(3, 3),activation = swish,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2))
classifier.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2),strides=2))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Convolution2D(64,kernel_size=(3, 3),activation = swish,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Convolution2D(64,kernel_size=(3, 3),activation = swish,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2))
classifier.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2),strides=2))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.4))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
#classifier.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Dense(128,activation = swish))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
classifier.add(keras.layers.Dense( 4, activation = 'softmax'))
print(classifier.summary())
# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

The error is coming in the line:

```
classifier.add(keras.layers.Convolution2D(16,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape = (256,256,3),activation = swish,padding='same',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2))
```

I run the file with the following code:

```
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import set_printoptions
from keras import callbacks,regularizers,Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense, Flatten,Dropout,Input,Conv2D, MaxPool2D,BatchNormalization
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
set_printoptions(precision=4,suppress=True)
```

The error started coming when I added the L2 regularizer, before that it was working fine.

`

Comment: have you tried in this way `kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)`

Comment: Thank you so much, the error is not coming now.

Comment: I will write it to the answer please accept it

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
classifier.add(keras.layers.Convolution2D(16,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape = (256,256,3),activation = swish,padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
```